# H.264 Macroblock extraction

Tags: video, encoding, h.264

From my cursory understanding of the H.264 spec, it seems that the video is chunked into macroblocks with different frame types. The macroblocks themselves are 16x16.

**Question:**
Is it possible to read an h.264 encoded mp4 file, and output the I,P,B frames as 16x16 macroblock chunks. And if yes, can I then reconstitute the original video with these separate chunks?

**What I've tried:**
I have tried this project https://github.com/LukasBommes/mv-extractor but did not get the results I was expecting. It provided the I,P,B frames, but not split into the separate macroblocks.

Comment: Hi, if it's quiet then most likely you need to [improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76160121/edit). Ask a more clearer question... Right now you have: **(1)** _"Is it possible to read an h.264 encoded mp4 file, and output the I,P,B frames as 16x16 macroblock chunks?"_ Yes. That's what an h.264 decoder does. It decodes the frame bytes (removes compressions, reconstructs the image). **(2)** _"It provided the I,P,B frames, but not split into the separate macroblocks"_ What do you want 16x16 tiles? If yes, you can just extract that yourself as a section of the frame's image.

Comment: PS: Section means... Decode a Frame (use a video player/decoder), grab frame as Bitmap, then read the Pixels that represent your required Macroblock's area/position. Note: In an H264 file the macroblocks are just representative of an on-screen area. They are not actual pictures, the file just holds info about what the final pixel colours should be (for that block area, for example with Green Screen the instruction could be "This 16x16 block uses a colour from another block"). PPS: Clarify. Either you want the bytes that represent a macroblock, or you want the picture that it would have shown?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I want just the bytes in this case. My understanding is that I can get the I keyframes as images. What I would like to do is then take the P and B frames as just bytes broken up by macroblocks. With this information, I would also like to stitch the I P and B information back together to get the original video without losing quality. Is that possible? If so, is there code somewhere you think would do that.

Comment: Anyone have an idea on how to perform this? Would love to figure out a way to get the I,P,B frames (P and B as just bytes broken up by the macroblocks). Then would it be possible to recreate the original video with just this information?

Comment: Sorry but your question is still un-answerable. Mostly because you're not saying where you are stuck in this following process (assuming raw h264 not inside an MP4): Get access to file bytes. In those bytes... **(1)** Find a keyframe NAL unit (starts with byte like `65`) so look for a NAL start code `00 00 001` and check next byte (as NAL header) if it is `65`... **(2)** After this 1 byte NAL header, comes the slice header, then next comes the macroblock header then the macroblock data... Parsing Slices and Macroblocks means using a Golomb-code decoder function (easy to make, check the web).

Comment: **(3)** Analyse the **bits of each byte** according to the spec... for example, what is first entry of a Slice? It is `first_mb_in_slice` (tells the X/Y pos, of this specific slice section of the frame image) and is of various bits length. This is where your Golomb-codes decoder comes in. You give it those bits and it gives you back a number of expected bits  length to read. Check every expected entry ac(according to spec) as you move forward and you will reach the end of Slice header, now you're at the Macroblock header... repeat the Golomb decoding as you parse the required variables.

Comment: PS: Too many tabs, Forgot to click post... **(4)** Now you've reached a macroblock header. Check the specs for its structure and get those expected bits.... Practice getting up this stage. On this forum, a definition of **a real programming question** is when it is asking about something in one of those four above steps and also possibly showing code or output that needs fixing.... PPS: **Why do you need individual macroblocks instead of one full frame**? Some macroblocks are just a note to use the same MB data from a different frame so then you'll need to parse a different frame for the data.

Comment: Wow this is great! I can use this as a good starting point. Thank you!